# Search only by Field instead of entire content

Tags: templating, search

I have a vacancy's website which has a couple of search forms spread around the website. The craft standard search form works great, the only problem is I need to search only by the **title field** instead of all the content in the entries.

So my question is..

**Is it possible to search only by title field?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
{% set searchTerm = craft.request.getParam('q') %}    
{% set query = craft.entries({
        search: 'title:*' ~ searchTerm ~ '*',
        limit: 5,
        locale: craft.locale,
        order: 'score'
    }) %}
```

You can leave out the `*` on both sides if you only want to search for full word matches. Also, this might help you take it further: https://craftcms.com/docs/searching

Comment: That did the trick. Couldn't figure it out straight from the docs though.